# Appcelerator Titanium Calendar Module Issue

Tags: module, calendar, titanium, appcelerator

I have been having a bit of trouble getting this module to work: https://github.com/smontgomerie/Appcelerator-Calendar-Module.

After playing around with my application's tiapp.xml file and the module's manifest file, I have managed to get Titanium to detect the module. However, upon launching my app, I receive a "module not found" error.

I was wondering if anyone has managed to get this module working, and if so - how?

Thanking anyone who can help in advance!

Comment: hm.. did u include your module with Ti.include(..)?

Comment: Did you change your tiapp.xml file correctly? Please provide the snippet.

Comment: Yes and Yes, I am certain that I have done both correctly as Titanium is actually detecting the module on start-up of the emulator (echoed out in [INFO]).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the alternative [calendar module](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/2179)?